# Hive failed to pick up the selected column

Tags: hadoop, hive

The below code creates the sample employee table. Everything works fine, but it returns the whole data while picking up only required column.I don't understand where I'm going wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
name STRING,
salary FLOAT,
subordinates ARRAY<STRING>,
deductions MAP<STRING, FLOAT>,
address STRUCT<street:STRING, city:STRING, state:STRING, zip:INT>
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\002'
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\003'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Sample Data used:

```
John Doe^A100000.0^AMary Smith^BTodd Jones^AFederal Taxes^C.2^BState
Taxes^C.05^BInsurance^C.1^A1 Michigan Ave.^BChicago^BIL^B60600
```

Sample query used:

```
SELECT name FROM emp;
```

Returned Result:

```
John Doe^A100000.0^AMary Smith^BTodd Jones^AFederal Taxes^C.2^BState
Taxes^C.05^BInsurance^C.1^A1 Michigan Ave.^BChicago^BIL^B60600
```

Comment: i think issue is your data is not getting parsed. whole row is going under name column. and if m not wrong other columns values must be null.

Comment: if i tried to get all the fields by select * from emp , getting nulls in between.it ensures not all column going under name column..

Comment: yes you are rite.all the fields going under name column.do you know what's the problem here?

Comment: one suggestion instead of using \001, \002 can't you specify ^A, ^B, ^C as it seems to be a simple text data and should work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that, by the looks of your input data, the control characters have been written as plain text, so "^A" will not be recognised as character \001. You can try to open the input file with a hexadecimal viewer and see if this is correct or not.

However if this is correct, you need to tell Hive to separate the fields by a String instead of a character. This is not as simple since you need to use a [RegexSerDe](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/RegexSerDe.html), and this does not allow to use column types such as `MAP` or `ARRAY`. The easiest solution would be to modify your input data and change the delimiters to single characters.